# How to rename Folder (Bucket Display Name) in android using Mediastore APIs

Tags: android, android-studio, mediastore

I am using **Mediastore** to retrieve **Videos** and I also group them by "**Bucket Display Name**".

the problem is, I can **rename or delete** a video as i have their **IDs and URIs**. But i am stuck in doing this for the Folders(Buckets). I want to rename and delete Folders too.

I've tried

`File folder=new File(videoUri).getParentFile();`

but it's not working. Any hint is greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: You should get MediaColumns.DATA from the content resolver. It contains a direct file path for the media store entry and you can use the path to construct java.io.File. And then, File().getParentFile() will work and you can rename it. However, note that you must have appropriate permissions. Please refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA

Comment: Try to rename a folder first.

Comment: The .DATA column is not available in Android Q+.

Comment: No. Although the DATA column is deprecated in Android Q, it still available until the newest Android R. Deprecation does not mean that you cannot use it from now. Instead, it means that you may not able to use it in some time in the future and you should not use it from now. Moreover,  the official docs I linked above says you are allowed to use it in Android 11 (R). IMHO it will be remained for a long time due to the change of scoped storage policy in Android R.

Comment: Mmmm.. i will check tomorrow. Interesting step back. Thanks @Brian Oh.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. It did change the folder (Bucket Name) But didn't Update it.